# How to remove the <text:soft-page-break /> element from the ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

**Summary:** Having the following fragment in the form of the ElementTree element...

```
<text:p>Text of the paragraph, <text:span>wrapped text</text:span>
continuing <text:soft-page-break />and more of the text.</text:p>
```

How can I remove efficiently the `<text:soft-page-break />` element from the structure?

**Details:** I have `content.xml` file extracted from the `my.odt` file stored in the *OpenDocument* format (from Microsoft Word). My goal is to transform it to the AsciiDoc format. This means to recognize important parts, and to throw away the other parts.

I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse the XML file into memory. As the document does not have a good internal markup (you know how the users use the WYSIWYG tools), the transformation is tailored for the specific document (a book).

Say, I want to implement the function like `remove_empty_elements(root, 'text:soft-page-break', namespaces)`. I am aware of the `element.remove(subelement)` that can remove subelement from the parent element. The following implementation is not correct:

```
def remove_empty_elements(root, tag, namespaces):
    lst = []
    for parent in root.iterfind('.//' + tag + '/..', namespaces):
        e = parent.find('./' + tag, namespaces)
        if e.text is None:
            lst.append((parent, e))

    for parent, e in lst:
        parent.remove(e)
```

It is not correct, because the `and more of the text.` part belongs to the removed element (as `e.tail`), and the text would be removed with the element.

How would you join the `e.tail` text to the tail of the previous element? Or is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that relies only on the [documented API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) of `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

sample = '''
<doc xmlns:text="http://example.com/">
    <text:p>Text of the paragraph, <text:span>wrapped text</text:span>
    continuing <text:soft-page-break />and more of the text.</text:p>
</doc>
'''

class MyTreeBuilder(ET.TreeBuilder):

    def start(self, tag, attrib):
        if not tag.endswith('soft-page-break'):
            return super(MyTreeBuilder, self).start(tag, attrib)

    def end(self, tag):
        if not tag.endswith('soft-page-break'):
            return super(MyTreeBuilder, self).end(tag)

def my_fromstring(data):
    parser = ET.XMLParser(target=MyTreeBuilder())
    parser.feed(data)
    return parser.close()

print ET.tostring(my_fromstring(sample))
```

Comment: Thanks Vasiliy. I have solved it differently -- during extraction of the string, but things in your answer are new to me and good to know. Have a good time.